# Graph API OneNote C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I was looking at the Microsoft Graph API to insert pages into OneNote, I was able to get the URI's and that came back fine. My question is how do I build a C# method that takes the Creating Pages URI and implement that into a C# application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at the OneNote [developer sample for ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-tutorial#create-a-onenote-app-for-aspnet-mvc) which is a starting point.

Otherwise, add some code with what you have already tried (as per SO's ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guides).